# UDP Packets Lost (Ubuntu 18.04 into Windows 10)

Tags: udp, ubuntu-18.04, wireshark, windows-firewall

I am trying to send UDP packets from Linux machine (Ubuntu 18.04 ) to a windows 10 machine. But the packets are not received at the Windows machine. I have already send UDP packets from Windows 10 to Linux machine and was successful. I have wireshark installed on both machines to debug. Pings are working from Linux to Windows as well.

The udp packets from Linux machine seems to be send as per Wireshark. However the wireshark on windows machine shows nothing regarding UDP packets from Linux machine. I have added inbound rules for the port on Windows machine, but still the issue persists. I have tried using different port numbers as well. Kindly let me know if there is anything missing from my end

Comment: You're in the wrong forum. StackOverflow is for programming questions only. This should be either in https://SuperUser.com or https://ServerFault.com

Comment: thanks for the info. Will switch to the responsible forums.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to active Symantec End Point Protection. So created an exception rule for the respective Sender IP address and everything works fine